# How do I replicate this 3 column layout without using a table?

Tags: css, layout

Feeling a bit frustrated at not being able to properly figure this out. I'm updating an old site and am trying to make this work without tables. I can do it with box flex but its unsupported by a lot of browsers. The layout is something like this

> [col-1-as-small-as-possible][ col-2-should-use-all-space
>   ][col-3-as-small-as-possible]

Columns don't need to be the same height, and the overall width of all 3 columns combined is constrained by a parent.

If I use floats I can't get the middle column to expand. The width of the col-1 and col-2 are *not* fixed widths.

Any solutions that don't feel worse then the problem(tables)?

here's an example of the table based solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7dsCV/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a strange solution, but setting `overflow: hidden` on the middle `div` will give you what I believe you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/qrBXL/

I've been meaning to figure out why this happens but haven't gotten around to it yet.  My best guess is that `overflow` only works on rectangular containers and floats wrapping within the `div` make it essentially non-rectangular.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem; I added a table example in the question. The middle column will be filled with text; it should be bound within the size of that column. If I fill up your middle col with text it breaks =\

Comment: Actually, you added tons of text to the right column.  I assumed this column, while being dynamic, would not extend too far.  It works with the middle having lots of text, not the sides.  http://jsfiddle.net/qrBXL/4/

Comment: My apologies, I did add text to the wrong column. That's insane ... testing it across all target browsers now.

Comment: This works in IE7+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox -- you sir, should you ever come to Minneapolis, I will buy a beer.

Comment: The reason this works is described [here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats). Yay for block formatting contexts!

Comment: (+1)  Incredibly awesome.  Can't believe I haven't discovered this technique until today.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "small as possible" I still assume they have a fixed width. It would be bad to have different widths between the pages.
That being said, you can look at this article for a very good example of a layout which takes care of a lot of issues: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/
If you don't want to go through all of it, at the end you have all the code, ready to be copied & pasted.

Comment: The question specifically says they do not have a fixed width. Theses are not page columns. The linked article only works via fixed widths, but thank you anyway.